# I'm late vs I'm going to be late

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I'm late.

vs

> I'm going to be late.

What is the difference between their meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm going to be late" means "I know I have no chance of getting to my destination in time".

"I'm late" could mean that you are behind schedule in the timetable you had planned for your daily activities (also "I'm running late"). You might use it when you arrive ("I'm sorry I'm late"), but later on you would say "I was late" or "I arrived late".

Answer (score 1):

I'm late - I'm late now, usually in case when you arrived some place, and you couldn't keep appointments.

I'm going to be late - prediction of situation. Therefore, usually used in case when you hurry up